# Exclude classes and namespaces from serialization?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to serialize a rather large structure with Jackson.
However, it's also trying to export a lot of substructures I will never need (causing a `JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class`)

So how can I exclude classes and namespaces from serialization?

Alternatively, how can I flag properties of my classes as excluded/ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **transient** keyword if you have actually access to the substructure you want to exclude.

> transient is a Java keyword which marks a member variable not to be
>   serialized when it is persisted to streams of bytes. When an object is
>   transferred through the network, the object needs to be 'serialized'.
>   Serialization converts the object state to serial bytes. Those bytes
>   are sent over the network and the object is recreated from those
>   bytes. Member variables marked by the java transient keyword are not
>   transferred, they are lost intentionally.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient

Answer (score 0):

Please give an example for *exclude classes and namespace* but for properties for which you might not control the source code you can use the following on types and fields

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"propertyName", "otherProperty"})
```

[Here's the javadoc.](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)

Here's an example

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "name" })
public class Examples {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
        Examples examples = new Examples();
        examples.setName("sotirios");
        Custom custom = new Custom();
        custom.setValue("random");
        custom.setNumber(42);
        examples.setCustom(custom);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

        mapper.writeValue(writer, examples);
        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "value" })
    private Custom custom;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Custom getCustom() {
        return custom;
    }

    public void setCustom(Custom custom) {
        this.custom = custom;
    }

    static class Custom {
        private String value;
        private int number;
        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
        public void setNumber(int number) {
            this.number = number;
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
{"custom":{"number":42}}
```

In other words, it ignored `Examples#name` and `Custom#value`.